# Exponential Decay Question: The Half-Life of Cesium-137 is 30 Years. Suppose We Have a 100-mg Sample.

Tags: calculus

(a) Find the mass that remains after t years?

t = 30

$P_o=100$

The equation for decay is $P_oe^{kt}$

How do I find the relative growth rate?

So after realizing that the half the amount of 100mg would be 50mg I placed the 50 mg in my formula as the result. Thus,

$50 mg=100e^{k30}$

I divided both sides by 100:

$\frac{50}{100}=\frac{100e^{k30}}{100}$

$ln\ 0.5=ln\ e^{k30}$

$\frac{ln\ 0.5}{30}=k$

k= -0.023

> Answering part (b) should be easy after I find part (a)

(b) How much of the sample remains after 100 years?

$P(100)=100e^{-0.023\cdot 100}$

$10.025\ mg=100e^{-0.023\cdot 100}$

(c) After how long will only 1 mg remain?

Comment: Consider how much remains after 30 years, or after 60 years.

Comment: You have the information in the title : *the half-time is 30 years*. So, get $k$

Comment: So I assume it is 50 years?

Comment: @sjb - Take a look at my work now´. Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer to a) is correct.
Now it is really easy to solve b) and c) becuase you know the decay equation: 
$$
P(t)=P_0 e^{-0.023 t}
$$

so, for b) you have:
$$
P(100)=100 e^{-2.3} \approx 10 \mbox{ mg}
$$
and for c) you have to solve:
$$
1=100 e^{-0.023 t}
$$ 
and you find:
$$
t=-\dfrac{\ln{0.01}}{0.023} \approx 199.3  \mbox{ years}
$$

Answer (score 1):

In a, you need to give the units of $k$, but are otherwise correct.  For b, it is not rounded correctly and not given as an answer, but OK. For c, use the same equation as you have, $1 mg=100 mg e^{-0.23t}$ and solve for $t$

Comment: What are the units for k? Is it per year? Also, what do you mean when you wrote part b is not given as an answer? The answer is 10.025 mg. It may have been better to keep more decimals, but the answer is in the ball park. No?

Comment: Yes, the argument of the exponential has to be unitless, so that tells you how to measure $t$.  Yes, the answer is very close.  It should round to $10.026$